# how to under understand TDengine’s interval keyword and sliding?

Tags: tdengine

I was using TDengine’s continuous query. It is hard for me to understand this, since I was used to using MySQL.what’s more,TDengine support it with two key words “interval” and “sliding”. I test it with sql like

select  count(*) from ${table} interval(1m);
[image: interval result]

select  count(*) from ${table} interval(1m) sliding(30s);
[image: sliding result]

All the data in the table.
[image: all the data]

Does any one can help explain why came to that result?

Comment: please don't post images of text

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link, which accepts the usage of interval and sliding in detail.
https://taosdata.com/2021/11/12/3278.html

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon as they can be invalidated at any time. You need to extract the essential information into your post